# Translate riddle to math

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I have already solved this riddle, but I didn't like the method I had to use and would like to be able to solve it with more mathematical rigor.

I understand the basic idea for a problem like this: come up with a system of equations with at least as many equations as there are variables. But, I found myself having a hard time translating a portion of this riddle into algebra and had to resort to trying out values to find the solution. There **has** to be a better way, and that is what I'm looking for: how to rigorously express the portion of this riddle I am missing so that I can solve for it instead of experimentally plugging in values until all the equations are satisfied. Here is the riddle:

> I'm thinking of four numbers:
>
> - Rule 1: The sum of all four numbers is 31
> - Rule 2: Only one of the four is an odd number
> - Rule 3: The highest number minus the lowest number is 7
> - Rule 4: The difference between the two middle numbers is 2
> - Rule 5: There are no duplicate numbers
>
> Which four numbers are they?

- From Rule 2, I defined `A` as the odd number, and `B`, `C`, and `D` as the
  even numbers
- Arbitrarily, I assigned `B < C < D` (we can do this because there are no repeats)
- From Rule 1, I defined `A + B + C + D = 31`
- From Rule 5: I get `A != B != C != D`   (using `!=` to convey not equal)
- From Rule 4, I get `C - B = 2`
- From Rule 2 and 4, I know `B is even` and `C is even`, leaving A and D, one of which is odd, the other even. I have defined `D` as even, so `A` must be odd.
- At this point I don't know which is bigger, `A` or `D`, but I do know that `A < B  or  A > D`, one of the two.
- From Rule 3, `D - A = 7  or  D - B = 7`, but since I know `D - B` is an even number, I now know `A < B < C < D < 31`
- Rearrange `C = B + 2` and `D = A + 7`
- Substituting, I know `A + 2B + D = 29`, and then `2A + 2B = 22`
- Divide by 2 to get `A + B = 11`
- With the constraints that A is odd and B is even, that leaves only three possibilities for `A` and `B`: 
  `1 + 10` or `3 + 8` or `5 + 6`  Note that this is the step I don't like. I think there should be a better way to figure it out, rather than plugging in values. What am I missing? Probably something super simple.
- Trying all three of these combinations leads to `A=1 B=10 C=12 D=8`, which violates the total-order scheme I set up (arbitrarily), or `A=3 B=8 C=10 D=10` which violates Rule 5, or `A=5 B=6 C=8 D=12`, which obeys all the rules and sums to 31.

So that's how I got the answer of 5, 6, 8, and 12. But there has to be a more robust way to solve this. Please show me. High school was a long time ago. I'm probably just forgetting something basic.

Comment: To be honest, I pretty much like the way you solved this. You did a lot of smart work to end up with only three cases. I think that should be considered a success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the two smallest numbers be $a$ and $b$; the other two are $b+2$ and $a+7$. The sum of all four numbers is $31$, this simplifies to $a+b=11$. Since only one of the four numbers is odd, and $b$ and $b+2$ have the same parity, $a$ is odd. The four numbers are then, in increasing order,
$$a<11-a<13-a<a+7$$
The last inequality simplifies to $a>3$, and the first to $a<{11\over 2}$. The only odd number in this interval is $a=5$.

Answer (score 2):

There is an inherent indeterminancy because there are $4$ variables and only $3$ equations, but it "happens" that the solution is unique because of the other "soft" constraints.

For a slightly more direct derivation, let $a \gt b \gt c \gt d$ be the numbers (with the inequalities being strict because of Rule 5 "*no duplicates*") then the premise translates to:

$$
\begin{align}
& a+b+c+d=31 \tag{1} \\
& a-d=7 \tag{2} \\
& b-c=2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Solving the above with $d$ as a free variable i.e. substituting $(2)$ $a=d+7$ and $(3)$ $b = c+2$ gives:

$$d+7 + c + 2 + c + d = 31$$
$$2 c = 22 - 2 d$$

Then:

$$
\begin{align}
& c = 11 - d \\
& b = 13 - d \\
& a = d + 7
\end{align}
$$

Since $c > 1$ it must be that $d \lt 11$ and since $a \gt b$ it follows that $d \gt 3$. Then by Rule 2 $d$ must be odd, otherwise all of $a,b,c$ would be odd. This leaves $d \in \{5,7,9\}$ to check by hand one by one, giving the unique solution in the end $a = 12\,,\;\;b = 8\,,\;c = 6\,,\;d = 5$.